# CakePHP Containable is generating far too many queries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using ContainableBehavior to get deep associations on a find in my CakePHP 2.4 app. However, this is resulting in *far too many* SQL queries - into the thousands on one page.

To simplify my relations a little, it looks like this:

```
Post
    hasMany
        - Sighting
            hasMany
                - Field
                    belongsTo
                        - Fieldtype
```

Now, when I do a find() specifying these in my `contain` statement, my DebugKit MySQL log is filled with queries like this, repeated over and over:

```
SELECT `Fieldtype`.`id`, `Fieldtype`.`name` FROM `dev_db`.`fieldtypes` 
AS `Fieldtype` WHERE `Fieldtype`.`id` = 48
```

Basically, it's doing a manual find for each and every `Field`'s `Fieldtype`, even when it should already have the data.

**Is there a solution for returning this kind of deep association that does not duplicate queries?** I've tried using [the Linkable behavior](https://github.com/lorenzo/linkable), however

- That only seems to work with one-to-one relationships (you can't use
  Link like Contain to get data from a hasMany relationship)
- You have to start with your main model- you can't Contain all your
  child records, and then use Linkable to hook up the models they belongTo.

Code:

```
$this->Paginator->settings['contain'] = array(
    'User',         
    'Sighting' => array(
        'Field' => array('Fieldtype')
    ),          
);
```

Comment: what is your recursive set to?

Comment: `$this->Post->recursive = -1;`. Containable is working exactly as it should, however it's turning out to be very inefficient.

Comment: Containable should have worked for you... Try `unbind()` and see if it works

Comment: Containable is working. It is loading all the data I want. I'm getting Fields that belong to Sightings that belong to Posts, as well as the Fields' Fieldtypes.  However, ContainableBehavior gets the Fieldtypes by doing a find for each and every Field using the Field's `fieldtype_id`, which is dog-slow. It should be doing this with joins, no?